# Copy data from one sheet (data) to another (summary)

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to populate one worksheet (summary) with data from a large data dump held in another worksheet (data).

**This is going to be sent to budget holders within my organisation who will be able to filter on their cost centre and view their staff group.**

**Summary worksheet**
This is structured as follows:

```
|   |    A     |      B      |     C     |      D      |
| 1 | Please choose a cost centre:         [Textfield] |
| 2 |          |             |           |             |
| 3 | POSITION | STAFF GROUP | PAY GRADE |             |
| 4 | [Data will go here]
| 5 | [Data will go here]
| 6 | [Data will go here]
```

**Data worksheet**
This is structured as follows (although with 3,600 rows and not 4):

```
|   |    A         |      B      |     C     |      D      |
| 1 | POSITION     | STAFF GROUP | PAY GRADE | COST CENTRE |
| 2 | Typist       | A&C         | Junior    | 3000        |
| 3 | Manager      | A&C         | Mgmt      | 3200        |
| 4 | Typist       | A&C         | Junior    | 3000        |
| 5 | Receptionist | A&C         | Junior    | 3000        |
```

**The Exam Question**
Using the textfield to select cost centre 3000, how can I populate the *Summary* worksheet with the two rows of data from the *Data* worksheet? Almost as if you could through a *pivot* table. Could this be done with formulae or will VBA be required?

Comment: look into an advanced filter.  It should do what you want without the need of vba.

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: @ExcelHero Using the copy to feature on the advanced filter will allow you to copy the filtered data to another sheet.  You just have to initiate the filter from the sheet where you want the data to go.  At least that is how I understand it.  http://excelsemipro.com/2011/03/copy-data-to-another-worksheet-with-advanced-filter/

Comment: @BarryBlade Two things. Firstly, there are THREE records in your data sheet with a cost centre of 3000, but your question is asking for the TWO rows? Secondly, you ask if this can be done with *formulae* yet you have tagged the question with `excel-vba`. Can you clarify your question please?

Comment: Many thanks all. I have added more detail to the question above. Notably the use case for this and the fact the data sheet contains about 3,600 rows.  @ExcelHero I will try your solution out. Looks promising. Hopefully still viable given my added detail above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**METHOD #1**

This is the formula way to achieve the filter.

On the Summary sheet, select the range `A4:C22`.

Click the Formula Bar at the top of the worksheet and paste the following formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Data!A2:C22,SMALL(IF($D$1=Data!$D$2:$D$22,ROW(Data!$D$2:$D$22)-ROW(Data!$D$2)+1),ROW()-3),{1,2,3}),"")
```

> This is an array formula and must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now, as you update the value in cell D1, the filtered results will appear.

Note: this assumes that you will have no more than 20 filtered results. If that assumption is incorrect then you will need to select a deeper range before you confirm the array-formula.

Note: this assumes that the data on the data sheet do not extend further down than row 22. If the data do, then change the references of `22` in the formula to a larger number.

**METHOD #2**

This is a VBA soltuion.

Place the following procedure in a standard code module:

```
Public Sub Barry()

    Const DATA = "data!a1"
    Const OUTPUT = "a3:c3"
    Const FILTER_VALUE_ADDRESS = "d1"
    Const FILTER_COLUMN = 4

    Dim rCrit As Range, rData As Range

    Set rData = Range(DATA).CurrentRegion
    Set rCrit = rData.Resize(2, 1).Offset(, rData.Columns.Count + 2)
    rCrit(1) = rData(1, FILTER_COLUMN): rCrit(2) = Range(FILTER_VALUE_ADDRESS)
    rData.AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy, rCrit, Range(OUTPUT)
    rCrit.Clear

End Sub
```

Switch to the Summary sheet and press Alt-F8 to bring up the Macro Dialog.

Run `Barry`.

Comment: @BarryBlade How did it go?

Comment: You're not just Excel's Hero...you're mine! The VBA works like a charm. I haven't tried the formula as the VBA is cleaner in my opinion